# How can I use a result in both the test and the result of a cond?

Tags: if-statement, clojure

I've got the following code:

```
(cond
  (case-1? (compute-1 x)) (compute-1 x)
  (case-2? (compute-2 x)) (compute-2 x)
  (case-3? (compute-3 x)) (compute-3 x))
```

I want to avoid repeated computations of `compute-1`, `compute-2`, and `compute-3`. One option is:

```
(let [result-1 (compute-1 x)
      result-2 (compute-2 x)
      result-3 (compute-3 x)]
  (cond 
    (case-1? result-1) result-1
    (case-2? result-2) result-2
    (case-3? result-3) result-3))
```

Now I'm not repeating computations, but instead if now `(case-1? result-1)` evaluates to true, `result-2` and `result-3` were computed for no reason.
Behaviorally I want something like this:

```
(let [result-1 (compute-1 x)]
  (if (case-1? result-1)
    result-1
    (let [result-2 (compute-2 x)]
      (if (case-2? result-2)
        result-2
        (let [result-3 (compute-3 x)]
          (if (case-3? result-3)
            result-3))))))
```

However this code is obviously quickly becoming unmanageable. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: If you don't want a macro or an external dep you can use `delay` to avoid the computation.

Answer (score 3):

There's a library called [better cond](https://github.com/Engelberg/better-cond) that solves exactly that problem with a macro.

It's used like this:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require
   [better-cond.core :as b]))

(b/cond
  :let [result-1 (compute-1 x)]
  (case-1? result-1) result-1

  :let [result-2 (compute-2 x)]
  (case-2? result-2) result-2

  :let [result-3 (compute-3 x)]
  (case-3? result-3) result-3)
```

That snippet will macroexpand to code that's similar to your last example.